# How to modify details of only a particular occurrence of a recurring calendar event using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a recurring calendar event. I want to modify the details of only the current day occurrence of the event using appscript.
(for eg changing title or adding/removing a room or modifying guest list etc)

When we do it manually it asks us to choose between "This event" or "All events".

How to do it using appscript?

Comment: What you want to do is possible.  Have you tried writing any code yet?  [Have you read the documentation?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation and I could not find any method or way which can uniquely identify an occurrence of a recurring event to perform the desired operations on it. Can you please guide me on this if you know the way?

Comment: You want the current day's event, correct? Why doesn't [`Calendar.getEventsForDay`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventsForDay(Date)) work?  You can further filter the results until you get the Calendar Event you want.

Comment: You are right, I had just figured it out some time earlier and posted my solution just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to getEventsForDay of current day (in my case) of that calendar and compare the eventId of the recurring event with events returned by getTodayEvents.

Suppose the task is to delete a room from the current day occurrence of the recurring event.

Initially I was doing the below which is wrong (it deleted the room from all the occurrences of the event)

```
    function deleteRoomFromEvent(roomCalendarId, eventId) {
    var mainEvent=
 CalendarApp.getCalendarById(roomCalId).getEventById(eventId);

   mainEvent.deleteEvent();
  }
```

Below code works (It only deletes the room from the current day occurrence of the event which is expected result)

```
       function deleteRoomFromEvent(roomCalendarId, eventId) 
       {
         var events= 
        CalendarApp.getCalendarById(roomCalendarId). 
        getEventsForDay(new  Date());
          for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
       if(events[i].getId() === eventId) 
        events[i].deleteEvent();
       }
       }
```